# Determine local variable name in AspectJ

Tags: variables, object, aspectj

I'm new with AspectJ and I try to do this:

Lets say I have 2 objects:
`var_obj1`, `var_obj2`.

They are of the same type: `MyObject`.

In my aspect, I'm using an `around()` advice on the `toString()` method on `MyObject`.
I want to return the **object variable name**

For example, if I call `toString()` on `var_obj1`, this method (on the aspect) should return: "hello from var_obj1".

and if I call `toString()` on `var_obj2`, this method (on the aspect) should return: "hello from var_obj2".

This should be done without saving the variable name in the object.

I'm searching for an AspectJ solution for this.

My current code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyObject var_obj1, var_obj2;
  var_obj1 = new MyObject();
  var_obj2 = new MyObject();

  System.out.println(var_obj1.toString());
  System.out.println(var_obj2.toString());
}
```

Aspect:

```java
String around(): execution(String com.example.shapes.MyObject.toString()) {
  var object_var_name = ""; // here we need to put the variable object name
  return "hello from "+object_var_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is **not possible** with AspectJ. First of all, because there's no [pointcut expression](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) to pick out join-points where the method execution (or rather *method-call*) is based on accessing a local variable. Besides that, you shouldn't build your application logic based on the naming or even the use of local variables, a method could be invoked without using a local variable at all. Consider the following examples:

```
new MyObject().toString();
someOtherObject.getMyObject().toString();
```

Both perfectly valid invocations of `toString()`, yet no local variables were used.